# Ajax request return value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax, jqgrid

I have an Ajax call to my controller action looks like this:

```
var m = $.ajax({
        mtype: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetBrandForValidation")',
        data: { actionparameter: value },
        async: false,
        cache: false
});
```

As u can see i return actionparametter to my controller and controller have to return either true or false which has to be my "m" value, but i cant get it to work. Any ideas?

Controller Code:

```
public virtual JsonResult GetBrandForValidation(string actionparameter)
{
    var vendorId = _service.GetVendorIdByUsername(GetUserName());
    bool k;
    var brands = _service.GetBrandsByVendor(vendorId);
    var brand = new BrandsViewModel();
    brand.BrandName = "Opret ny Brand...";
    brands.Add(brand);

    foreach (var brandsViewModel in brands)
    {
        if (brandsViewModel.BrandName == "Intet")
        {
            brandsViewModel.BrandName = "";
        }
    }

    var list = brands.Select(s => s.BrandName);
    if (list.Contains(actionparameter))
    {
        k = true;
    }
    else
        k = false;

    return Json(k,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And full function code :

```
var checkBrands = function(value, colname) {  
    var m = $.ajax({
                mtype: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetBrandForValidation")',
                data: { actionparameter: value },
                async: false,
                cache: false

    });
    if (m == true)
        return [true, ""];
    else
        return [false, "Brand eksistere ikke"];
};
```

Im quite new and very awfull at javascript, so dont judge hard

Comment: [The first A in AJAX isn't just decoration. :)](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer.aspx?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-ajax&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro)

Comment: The only problem I can see is that in the ajax call the folowing is missing..    dataType: "json",

Comment: @bzim — It isn't Ajax, its Sjax. See `async: false` and welcome to the wonderful world of browser UI locking.

Comment: didnt worked with json either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

```
var checkBrands = function (value, colname) {

      var m = $.ajax({
          mtype: "type",
          url: '@Url.Action("GetBrandForValidation")',
          async: false,
          cache: false,
          data: { actionparameter: value }

      }).responseText;


      if (m == 'true'){
          return [true, ""];
      }
      else return [false, "Brand eksistere ikke"];

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the ajax call being made in JavaScript? If so, mtype should be type.

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkBrands = function(value, colname) {  
$.ajax({
            mtype: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetBrandForValidation")',
            data: { actionparameter: value },
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                 if(data == 'm'){
                    //do something
                 }else{
                    //do something
                 }

            }
});

};
```